# Bash Script to send an E-mail using valid SMTP authentication

Tags: bash, email, authentication, smtp

How to write a bash script to send the alert mails with valid SMTP authentication ?

As I googled, The mailx is not working properly.

Is there any pure bash script to send mails using SMTP authentication ?

Comment: Any tcp/ip program will work, try telnet.

Comment: @User112638726 SMTP AUTH involves a lot more than simple TCP.  In fact only the `login` and `plain` mechanisms can be handled from a script.

Comment: @lcd047 What else do you need to do ?

Comment: @User112638726 Read some [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) docs to find out. _shrug_

Comment: What is the Linux distro and version you are using ?

Comment: @lcd047 I mean specifically for SMTP. That covers all the security protocols. You don't need them all to have valid SMTP auth, you only need to encrypt the email address and password.

Comment: @User112638726 Please consider understanding the specs before arguing.  SMTP supports full SASL.  You have to pick one of the mechanisms offered by the server.  If the server offers `PLAIN` or `LOGIN`, you stand a chance to authenticate manually.  If it wants only, say, `OTP` and `EAP-AES128`, you lose.

Comment: @lcd047 No if the server offers PLAIN or LOGIN then you will definitely authenticate manually.`OTP` is obsolete and `s/key` is used instead which you can use with telnet. And honestly i've never seen `EAP-AES128` before and searching it on google on brings up the wikipedia page you linked and then a load of gibberish pages.

Comment: @User112638726 Ok, feel free to post a working answer then, and I'll point you to a real server your solution won't be able to authenticate with. :)

Comment: @lcd047 obviously because I would have to tailor the solution to that specific server/mechanism of auth. But i'm not posting an answer, and i doubt you are as well, so this discussion is pointless.

Comment: I am using Ferdora 21 and CentOS 7